# How can I link AWS SSL to AWS Wordpress

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, wordpress, load-balancer

I have created an EC2 instance for WordPress on AWS. My domain, its hosted zone, and SSL certificate all run on AWS. 
Can you guys please help me to connect my domain with SSL certificate?

Really appreciate the help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by putting CloudFront in front of your EC2 instance; this will not only allow you to use a SSL certificate provided by AWS Certificate Manager, but will also speed up the delivery of your content.

You can read more about using CloudFront with Wordpress here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @hephalump, you can attach an SSL certificate on your CloudFront CDN distribution and use CloudFront to access your website.

You can also do the same thing with an Application Load Balancer (ALB) where you can put your SSL certificate on the ALB's HTTPS listener. In fact, you can terminate your HTTPS on the load balancer and have your load balancer and ec2 instance communicate using plain HTTP. This will put less load on your EC2 instance since it does not have to decrypt and encrypt your HTTPS traffic (sames goes with using CloudFront)...but of course you can't do this if you **NEED** to have end-to-end encryption for your website.

PS: SSL certificates from AWS Certificate Manager are free ( https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/ )